# After converting Spark data frame to pandas data frame, pandas data frame is throwing KeyError 0 when searching for a cell

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, databricks

I am running this in data bricks notebook.

I converted a spark data frame [250 rows x 2 columns] to pandas data frame using below method:

```
pandasDF = spark_df.toPandas()
```

this is successful and I was able to run below lines successfully:

```
print(pandasDF)
print(pandasDF.columns.tolist())
```

but when I tried to query a cell in pandas data frame I am getting error. Why is that?

```
print(pandasDF [0][1])

KeyError: 0
```

Additional details about the exception:

```
/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3022             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   3023                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 3024             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   3025             if is_integer(indexer):
   3026                 indexer = [indexer]

/databricks/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   3080                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   3081             except KeyError as err:
-> 3082                 raise KeyError(key) from err
```

Comment: Please can you provide the output of `print(pandasDF.head())`? You can also try to use `pandasDF.iloc[0]` to get the first row and `pandasDF.iloc[0, 1]` to get the cell of the first row and the second column. But I'm pretty sure you have names in your columns.

Comment: Yes, ```pandasDF.iloc[0, 1]``` is working, but ```pandasDF[0][1]``` is returning error